# How to pass a .txt file arg to a exe application?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need combine a .txt file with a .exe application. This process work correctly in my desktop, when I move the .txt on the .exe application. Could I do this with python?

Comment: What process? What do you mean by combine a .txt file with an .exe application?

Comment: So you drag a text file onto an exe and something happens?  Can you provide more details?

Comment: I have a .exe that convert a .pcl file (or .txt file work too) to pdf file. The input is a .pcl file (printer control language), when i do this in my windows desktop, i get a PDF like result. I need do this with code in python.. ;) shall you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you just do

```
from subprocess import call
call(["that.exe", "that.txt"])
```

or

```
import os
os.system("that.exe that.txt")
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you need to call `cmd \c` to run the exe?

```
from subprocess import call
call(["cmd", "/c", "that.exe", "that.txt"])
```

or

```
import os
os.system("cmd /c that.exe that.txt")
```

**Edit:**

If you want to send keystrokes to the process once it is called you can use subprocess to get an object that can followup like that.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "that.exe", "that.txt"], shell=True)
proc.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

**Final edit:**

you might need to use stdin=subprocess.PIPE on that...

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "that.exe", "that.txt"] ,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

Comment: Now, I need send a <ENTER> key after do this, because the .exe  keep waiting for this key to close the process. (Press enter to continue). How can i add this function??